# Call to a member function getRealPath() on null

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I wanted to ask on how can i put a error message if theres no uploaded file but they press the upload button. How can I put an error message if the getRealPath is empty?

```
public function importExcel()
    {
        if (empty(Input::file('import_file')->getRealPath())) {
            return back()->with('success','No file selected');
        }
        else {
        $path = Input::file('import_file')->getRealPath();
        $inserts = [];
        Excel::load($path,function($reader) use (&$inserts)
        {
            foreach ($reader->toArray() as $rows){
                foreach($rows as $row){
                    $inserts[] = ['biometrics' => $row['biometrics'], 'first_name' => $row['first_name'], 'last_name' => $row['last_name'], 'date' => $row['date'], 'emp_in' => $row['emp_in'], 'emp_out' => $row['emp_out']];
                }
            }
        });

        if (!empty($inserts)) {
            DB::table('attendances')->insert($inserts);
            return back()->with('success','Inserted Record successfully');                  
        }


        return back();
        }

    }
```

Comment: make a proper validation for your file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put an if before calling the getRealPath() function

```
if( Input::file('import_file') ) {
    $path = Input::file('import_file')->getRealPath();
} else {
    return back()->withErrors(...);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set error message like below

return redirect()->back()->with('errors', 'No file selected');

And then show error message in blade like mention in laravel documention.
It store message in session and you can easily show sesssion messages in blade file like below

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <!-- Form Error List -->
    <div class="alert alert-danger error">
        <strong>Whoops! Something went wrong!</strong>

        <br><br>

        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```